# Switching "maven-assembly-plugin" on/off

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Our current DevOps environment runs `mvn package` and auto-deploys the jar artifact in a private Maven repository and all target folder is cached for later use. But the project has also a `maven-assembly-plugin` set up what packages a second jar file (a fat jar suffixed as -`jar-with-dependencies`).

We don't want the "fat jar" to be generated by `maven-assembly-plugin` and so stored in that cache along with other files in that case.

Is there a way to switch `maven-assembly-plugin` on and off by command line (or any other property or environment variable) to run it only when explicitly required?

Comment: Why is it in your build if you don't need it or don't like it?

Comment: It's used in another situations (manually). Very specific, and should be explicitly required.

Comment: Then you should use a profile and deactivate that by default... apart from that why using something manually ? Do you use CI/Cd?

Comment: It's an occasionally deploy for a legacy environment.

Comment: Produce the package via separate module and deploy it to your repository manager that's it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the property `assembly.skipAssembly` to `true`.

Either on command line ( with `-Dassembly.skipAssembly=true`) or in the POM itself.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach (IMHO), would be to define the plugin in its own profile. Inside your `pom.xml`, you add a `profiles` section, and in that a `profile` that would include the plugin:

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>assemble</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <!-- All the configuration you have for the plugin -->
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then, by default, this plugin will **not** be called. When you want to call it, you can explicitly enable this profile with the `-P` flag:

```sh
mvn package -Passemble
```